# How to sum up total in an index view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on an invoice system in a homemade CRM. I try to sum up the price for all of my items to get the grand total.
I don't know how to get the grandtotal in my index view.

Here is my table in factures/**show**.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="text-right">Prix</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($facture->items as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$item->description}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{$item->prix}} $</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">TPS</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ $item->calcultps() }} $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">TVQ</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ $item->calcultvq() }} $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-right">Total</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ $item->calculgrandtotal() }} $</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my table in factures/**index**.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead><tr>
        <th><p># de facture</p></th>
        <th><p>Date</p></th>
        <th><p>Description</p></th>
        <th><p>Client</p></th>
        <th class="text-right"><p>Montant</p></th>
        <th class="text-right"><p>TPS</p></th>
        <th class="text-right"><p>TVQ</p></th>
        <th class="text-right"><p>Grand total</p></th>
    </tr></thead>
    @foreach($factures as $facture)
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ URL::to('factures/' . $facture->id) }}">{{$facture->id}}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $facture->created_at->format('d F Y') }}</td>
            <td>{{ $facture->courtedescription}}</td>
            <td>{{ $facture->client->prenom}} {{ $facture->client->nom}}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ $facture->montant}} $</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ $facture->tps}} $</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ $facture->tvq}} $</td>
            <td class="text-right"> IDONTKNOW $</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

here is my **Item.php model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Item extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['nom', 'prix'];

    public function facture()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Facture');
    }

    public function calcultps(){
        $total = DB::table('items')->sum('prix');
        $tps = $total *0.05;
        echo $tps;
    }

    public function calcultvq(){
        $total = DB::table('items')->sum('prix');
        $tvq = $total *0.09975;
        echo $tvq;
    }

    public function calculgrandtotal(){
        $totalsanstaxes = DB::table('items')->sum('prix');
        $tps = $totalsanstaxes *0.05;
        $tvq = $totalsanstaxes *0.09975;
        echo $totalsanstaxes+$tps+$tvq;
    }

}
```

and my **Facture.php model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Facture extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Client');
    }

    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany('Item', 'facture_id');
    }

}
```

my **index** function for my **FacturesController**.php

```
public function index()
{
    $factures = Facture::all();
    return View::make('factures.index')->withFactures($factures);
}
```

my **show** function for my **FacturesController**.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $facture = Facture::find($id);
    return View::make('factures.show')->withFacture($facture);
}
```

I tried these (in the factures/index.blade.php) without success:

```
{{ $item->calculgrandtotal() }}
{{ $items->calculgrandtotal() }}
{{ $facture->items->calculgrandtotal() }}
```

and this returns an array

```
{{$facture->items}}
```

but this doesn't work

```
{{$facture->items->prix}}
```

I know there is something I don't understand here. and I wonder how to print out the grandtotal in my index view for each of the invoice?

Comment: Try using `return` instead of `echo` within your model functions. As echo does not return anything.

Comment: Also you calling the functions on a collection not the model, run through the collection and call it on a model. As hasMany will return a `Eloquent\Collection` object.

Comment: @MattBurrow How should I proceed to call it on a model?

Comment: You could make them `static` methods and you can call them like so; `Item::calculgrandtotal()` as the return types do not retrieve any sets of models. Then you can pass them into your view, and then display them.

Answer (score 0):

I used the comment of @MattBurrow (thank you) and I managed to print out what I want using this:

**index**.blade.php

```
{{ Item::calculgrandtotal() }}
```

**Item**.php model

```
static function calculgrandtotal(){
    $totalsanstaxes = DB::table('items')->sum('prix');
    $tps = $totalsanstaxes *0.05;
    $tvq = $totalsanstaxes *0.09975;
    return $totalsanstaxes+$tps+$tvq;
}
```